# How to integrate Azure DevOps Servers repositories with Azure DevOps Services Pipelines

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines

We recently planning to move to the Azure DevOps SaaS version. Here we going to create the pipelines based on source code, Repos of on-premise Azure DevOps Server 2020.1.1. I tried with "other git" Service connection but the results not much expected. It is failing when am creating with PAT. So I created with my credentials. Auto triggering is not working when new code check-in and other branches are not showing except the master.

Then after I created a service connection based on "Azure repos/Team Foundation Server", But the service connection not showing on while creating the classic pipeline. Please some one help me, how can we create the pipelines in Azure DevOps Services based on On-Premise Azure DevOps server repos. How can we integrate both. Please someone help me on this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To integrate TFS repo with Azure DevOps Pipeline, you could use "Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server" service connection type:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-repos

[image]

To communication from TFS with Azure DevOps, you need to Ensure the following DevOps IP addresses are allowed for inbound connection on your local TFS machine:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#inbound-connections

Comment: but am not understanding how to use it on pipeline.